# why do floated divs obey an iframe?

Tags: html, iframe, css-float

For example:

http://jsfiddle.net/58AR7/

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">

<iframe class="frame" width="960" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?...</iframe>


<div id="article1">
</div>

<div id="article2">
</div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#content {
width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
overflow: auto;
height: 100%;}

#article1 {
float: left;
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
background-color: black;}

#article2 {
float: right;
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
background-color: black;}
```

Why do the two divs, article1 and article2, not float up towards the parent container (#content)? Why is the boundary of the iframe obeyed and thus the two divs floated below it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`float` means "Move left or right and allow *subsequent* elements to bubble up beside me".

Floating an element won't make *it* move up. You would have to float the iframe to cause the article divs to move beside it.

Comment: Ah, that's confusing. In the two html books that I have it states a floated element will be removed from the normal flow and positioned either to the left or right of the parent element i.e. the container. Block level elements are oblivious to floats yet inline elements will obey the boundaries of a floated element.

Comment: Nevermind, I rechecked one of my books and its description is inline with what you described.